# Why does it give an error? ui->graphicsView

Tags: qt

My goal is to print a QImage which consists of random RGB values. However, I got this error:

> No member named 'graphicsView' in 'Ui::MainWindow'

My code is here:

> 

```
int sizeX = 300; int sizeY = 300;

QImage img = QImage(sizeX, sizeY, QImage::Format_RGB32);
for(int i=0; i<sizeX; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<sizeY; j++){
        img.setPixel(i, j, qRgb(rand()%256, rand()%256, rand()%256));
    }
}
QGraphicsScene *graphic = new QGraphicsScene(this);
graphic->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
ui->graphicsView->setScene(graphic);
m_ig = new ImageGenerator;
connect(m_ig, &ImageGenerator::sigTest, this, &MainWindow::slotTest);
```

Thanks. Best regards!

Comment: The error message seems fairly clear: the type pointed to by `ui` has no member named `graphicsView `.  Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] including the `ui` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure that `Graphics View` widget is added to your MainWindow form (usually mainwindow.ui file) in Design section of QtCreator.
2. Check if its `objectName` is actually **graphicsView**.
3. Try to rebuild your project.